# UWP error after inserting a blank page

Tags: xaml, uwp

After adding ShowBg.xaml as a new page to my Windows UWP (using VS2017) I immediately get an error:

Code generated by VS:

```
Namespace Global.BIS

Partial Class ShowBG
    Implements Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector
    Implements Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector2


    <Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks", "14.0.0.0")>  _
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>  _
    Public Sub Connect(ByVal connectionId As Integer, ByVal target As Global.System.Object) Implements Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect
            Me._contentLoaded = true
    End Sub
    <Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks", "14.0.0.0")>  _
    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>  _
    Public Function GetBindingConnector(connectionId As Integer, target As Object) As Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector Implements Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector2.GetBindingConnector
        Dim returnValue As Global.Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector = Nothing
        Return returnValue
    End Function
End Class

End Namespace
```

As said: I added no code manually. Now I get a compile error for the line
  **Me._contentLoaded = true**

```
Error   BC30456 "_contentLoaded" ist kein Member von "ShowBG".  BIS C:\...\test\BIS\obj\x86\Debug\ShowBG.g.vb   24  Aktiv
```

I neither understand this error nor is google my friend concerning this.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to empty bin and obj folder and clean solution through build> clean solution and restart your project then build it. If app work fine before adding that page

Comment: Worked - thank you!

Comment: :) Glad it works. It is because when last time your app is debug , "Page.g.YourProjectType " e.g "page.g.vb" stuck in vs process and  visual studio unable to update that component and launch it with old config or codes , then it is not aware of any new modification of new item then it invoke exception. And it is like a person who is not aware of any new member in a family and deny to identify any new menber

Comment: Sorry for asking: why did you not enter that as a solution, but as a comment? So I cannot mark it as a solution (and you did not gain any reputation)

Comment: Okay :)..............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times visual studio process existing or previous debugging files ,so next time when you debug existing files is not updated with new changes or unknown to new changes.

**Error - Old debugging Files not updated with changes.

so you need to follow these steps-

1) Goto Build > Clean Solution and Close vs.

2) Empty "bin" , "obj" folder of project.

3) You Should also view in taskmanager for any running process of .vs and close it.

4) Then Reopen Your Project and Build it.